# Какова сложность реализованного алгоритма?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, c++11, c++17, сложность

Написал функцию, которая удаляет из массива строки, встречающиеся четное число раз. Мне нужно оценить ее временную сложность.

В ней два прохода по всем элементам входного массива, так что вроде как сложность равна O(N). Но там присутствует работа с std::map, операции с которым выполняются за O(logN). То есть, сложность должна быть O(N*LogN)? И возможно ли сделать ее в таком случае O(N)? Уточнение: порядок строк должен оставаться прежним, так что, сортировать нельзя.

```
std::vector<std::string> remove_even_strings(std::vector<std::string> & ref)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::map<std::string, size_t> srch;
    
    for (auto & r : ref)
    {
        auto [f, s] = srch.insert(std::make_pair(r, 1));
        if (s == false)
        {
            srch.at(r) = srch.at(r) + 1;
        }
    }
    
    for (auto & r : ref)
    {
        if (srch.at(r) % 2 == 1)
        {
            result.push_back(r);
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Похоже на то. Плюс куча дублирования данных. Если входной вектор далее не нужен, то намного эффективней отсортировать его, потом за один проход выкинуть лишнее и далее пользоваться им же

Comment: `map` -> `unordered_map` чтобы убрать логарифм из сложности.

Comment: @avp Забыл уточнить, функция не должна менять порядок строк в массиве. Сортировка его поменяет. Сейчас исправлю описание.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Пишут, что у unordered_map операция может быть вплоть до O(N^2) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unordered_map-in-cpp-stl/

Comment: imho можно попробовать следующий алгоритм. Делаем массив индексов входного вектора строк. Сортируем его, используя в качестве ключа строки. Потом помечаем строки, подлежащие удалению и удаляем их за еще один проход по вектору (или копируем их в вектор-результат, если нужна копия)ю А вообще, все зависит от размера вектора. Если там пара десятков строк, то любой простой алгоритм сойдет

Comment: Среднее время одного обновления/запроса - константа, худшее время - линейное. Если не ставить целью специально атаковать контейнер, вероятность того что время больше чем константа чрезвычайно мала.

Comment: @avp Спасибо, интересный вариант, попробую.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да, действительно, вы правы, я ошибся. Буду использовать unordered_map.

Comment: @Sergey U, а вы внимательно прочли в каких условиях 0(1) может быть сопоставим с сложностью вплоть до O(N^2)?

Comment: Если вы сразу примете копию входного массива, а не по ссылке, то можно использовать алгоритм @avp из 1-го комментария. Вы же всё равно потом создаете копию, чтобы вернуть.